# Examining DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, decompiling, directoryservices

I asked a yet unanswered/unsolved question yesterday regarding an "unknown" error when calling an LDAP server with a string. I've still not exactly discovered the problem, but I'd like to examine:

A) What *exactly* is being sent to the server and in what format;
B) What results are coming back.

I've looked into the construction of DirectoryServices, namely `DirectoryEntry()`, and I'm not sure how to go about disassembling it.

Has anyone done this before, or does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about doing it?

Comment: What string, what server? How are you connecting and how are you authenticating? What was the full exception thrown (including the call stack)? Before assuming there is something wrong with .NET, make sure your query is correct, that you are connecting to the correct server/port and that you are providing the correct credentials. If the actual error is "Unknown authentication method" as [in this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/514870/how-do-i-authenticate-with-ldap-via-the-command-line), you should modify the code to send the credentials expected

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you misunderstand me. I'm aware of that 0x8 code (and it's underlying -2xxx code), and I've checked the path and string that I have created - including escaping grammer and symbols. I can only assume that my expected output does not meet the requirements of our LDAP implementation here at this domain. Thus, since I cannot access the server connection logs, my next logical step is to analyse the string being passed to the LDAP server, in case there is a difference in formulation and I need to modify my assembly accordingly. Also, no LDAP documentation whatsoever here.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Also, note that we use a different set of naming conventions here - instead of a cn, we use uid=<sea> along with strck=value|value|potentialvalue. That is the extent of the documentation we have here, other than some advice for bash users to use a particular SDK for developing scripts - there is no documentation on how M$ kit is  used here.

Comment: `cn` and `uid` are **not naming conventions**. They are different attributes. Before assuming that .NET networking is broken, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177486/login-to-ldap-with-uid-instead-of-cn-in-dn-input). Decompiling .NET code won't help you retrieve the documentation of the (as yet unspecified) LDAP server. Of course, if you know the server and version number, you could check its online documentation

Comment: Have you used *any* other way to connect to the server and execute an LDAP query? Any command line utilities? How did you connect?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have previously successfully connected using an anonymous implementation of the Microsoft example on MSDN. This was successful, however anonymous functions are limited and do not allow users to authenticate to my application. Additionally, a directory search tool also allows users to login using LDAP, however this is written in COBOL. What I really would like to know is what exactly is being passed to the server, so that I can adjust my implementation accordingly.

Comment: Please. Give *some* specific information, otherwise no-one will be able to help. Unless your LDAP server is hand-coded, it has a name and a version. In any case, what you type is what is passed. If you think otherwise, use Fiddler or Wireshark to intercept the calls.

Comment: I'd also suggest you google for [select isn't broken](https://www.google.gr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=select%20isn%27t%20broken)